# Android targetSdkVersion 31 TelephonyManager listen SecurityException

Tags: android, telephonymanager

My app's targetSdkVersion is 31.

App crashed like this..

```
java.lang.SecurityException: listen
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3023)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3007)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2990)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2932)
        at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephonyRegistry$Stub$Proxy.listenWithEventList(ITelephonyRegistry.java:1074)
        at android.telephony.TelephonyRegistryManager.listenFromListener(TelephonyRegistryManager.java:265)
        at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.listen(TelephonyManager.java:7210)
        at kr.co.test.test.zn.run(EBZRNNoneVideoCallActivity.java:1206)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.internal.telephony.TelephonyPermissions.enforceCarrierPrivilege(TelephonyPermissions.java:676)
        at com.android.internal.telephony.TelephonyPermissions.checkReadPhoneState(TelephonyPermissions.java:169)
        at com.android.internal.telephony.TelephonyPermissions.checkCallingOrSelfReadPhoneState(TelephonyPermissions.java:94)
        at com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.checkListenerPermission(TelephonyRegistry.java:3424)
        at com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.listen(TelephonyRegistry.java:1090)
```

Documents say, use 'registerTelephonyCallback' methods and it requires READ_PHONE_STATE permission.
But, target version android 11 or higher, we must request the READ_PHONE_NUMBERS permission, instead of the READ_PHONE_STATE permission.
I tried 'registerTelephonyCallback' without permission but SecurityException occurred..

How can I handle this problem?

Comment: grant the necessary permissions. There are no other ways

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa grant all permissions but not working. It ignore the permission READ_PHONE_STATE and only READ_PHONE_NUMBERS is granted.